# Delete rows from python panda dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe has columns like ticket, host, drive model, Chassis, Rack, etc.

I want all the rows with value in the Chassis column equal to `'1025C-M3B'`, `'1026T-M3FB'`, `'2026TT-DLRF'` or `'SYS-2027TR-D70RF+'`. I want to delete the rest.

I tried

```
data2 = data1[data1.Chassis == '1025C-M3B' 
              or data1.Chassis == '1026T-M3FB' 
              or data1.Chassis == '2026TT-DLRF' 
              or data1.Chassis == 'SYS-2027TR-D70RF+']
```

Got

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Then tried

```
data2 = data1[data1.Chassis.all() == '1025C-M3B' 
              or data1.Chassis.all() == '1026T-M3FB' 
              or data1.Chassis.all() == '2026TT-DLRF' 
              or data1.Chassis.all() == 'SYS-2027TR-D70RF+']
```

Got

```
KeyError: u'no item named False'
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Comment: use bitwise or (`|`) instead of logical `or`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
data1[data1['Chassis'].isin(['1025C-M3B', '1026T-M3FB', '2026TT-DLRF','SYS-2027TR-D70RF+'])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use bitwise or (`|`) instead of logical `or`.

```html
data2 = data1[(data1.Chassis == '1025C-M3B') | (data1.Chassis == '1026T-M3FB') | (data1.Chassis == '2026TT-DLRF') | (data1.Chassis == 'SYS-2027TR-D70RF+')]
```

You can find plenty of reading material about the use of bitwise vs logical operations in numpy/pandas. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10063039/2096752).